# Perífrasis verbal "ir + infinitivo"

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

La frase del texto original dice:

> (1) He **could have killed** you.

El traductor español la traduce así:

> (2) **Iba a matarte**.

La perífrasis verbal *ir a hacer algo* expresa una acción planeada, ¿verdad? Yo esta frase la traduciría como *Hubiera podido matarte*. No entiendo por qué el traductor decidió traducirla con una forma que expresa el futuro próximo. El elemento de irrealidad se pierde en la traducción, ¿verdad? ¿O me equivoco?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Tal vez haya algo en el contexto que haya motivado esa traducción. De no ser así, no la entiendo.

Comment: Curioso, yo la habría traducido como _podría haberte matado_, y ahora me pregunto si eso dice lo mismo que _habría podido matarte_.

Answer (score 1):

El significado de la perífrasis verbal es aproximadamente como dijiste. No necesariamente tiene que ser una acción planeada; de hecho, reemplaza al tiempo verbal futuro simple, que se usa cada vez menos en castellano.

Habría que ver el contexto pero a mí esa traducción me parece poco apropiada. ¿Qué significa "He could have killed you"? ¿Significa lo mismo que "He could have tried and managed to kill you"? ¿O bien significa "He could have accidentally killed you"? Si es el primero la traducción podría estar bien en algún contexto; si es el segundo, está definitivamente mal.

Answer (score 0):

Estudiar español mediante traducciones es una arma de doble filo para los que no son nativos.
Los traductores se encargan de interpretar; es por esto, así como en la mayoría de los casos, que uno se va a encontrar con algo bastante distinto a lo que se se considera por traducción literal.

Otras interpretaciones de *He could have killed you* incluyen:

> —Pudo matarte. (= queda en duda si lo hizo o no; la especulación es débil).
>   —Pudo haberte matado. (= definitivamente no lo hizo porque preferió hacer otra cosa).

No obstante, la traducción *Iba a matarte* no parece del todo precisa; además, dudo bastante que quisiera usarla de esta manera, pues la implicancia es la que tú le habías dado con respecto a planear una acción.